# Load average is high after adding second drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, optical

My laptop was working fine and its load average was between 0.2 - 0.5 (and around 0.02 while doing nothing) until I decide to upgrade it with an SSD.

First I replaced my HDD with SSD, moving HDD into a HDD Caddy, removing the optical drive and putting HDD there instead.

- Both my SSD and HDD are capable of working with SATA III interfaces.
- However my HDD is working at SATA 2 mode:

  ```
  sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep SATA
  SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
  ```
- **[Seems](https://superuser.com/questions/1446464/can-hdd-caddy-reduce-drives-speed)** my optical drive interface is SATA 2.

#### Problem

The problem is whenever there is something in HDD Caddy (SSD, HDD, Doesn't matter) load average while doing nothing is around 1.5 - 2 and while system is just booted up is around 4.

#### What did I done?

- I have tried any combination of setup nothing takes any effects.

#### What else?

- CPU usage is normal and no process is consuming the CPU.
- If I only use one disk as the main hard drive load average is normal.
- If I even use one disk at the optical drive place, I get high load average.

Comment: So, If you have basically your old setup which had an 0.2-0.5 load, but instead of a CD/DVD drive you insert an SSD, the load goes up ? Have you tried to check where the load is coming from (i.e. iowait, etc) ?

Comment: That's correct, If I put anything in place of CD/DVD drive load goes up. Even if there is only SSD there with no other drive load average is always higher that on 1. I couldn't find anything interesting however there is always a `kworker` running with the state of `D` might be related to luks.

Comment: Check out the link by **WinEunuuchs2Unix**. It might be related to the caddy you use.

Comment: Does your HDD caddy have any buttons to switches ?

Comment: For uninterruptible sleep investigation, try some suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579826/load-average-high-on-only-one-of-16-hp-workstations/579836#579836).

Comment: @RobertRiedl :| Hmm, Stupidity of me! I Found the switch and changing its position seems making things much better. there is no `kworker` with state `D` anymore. Post it as an answer.

Comment: That is great news!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be related to the HDD caddy you use.

Please see if it has a button or a switch, in order to change the state of the caddy.

[image: this]

Answer (score 5):

There is an excellent Q&A with the same problem:

- [kworker consumes high cpu for external hard drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398520/kworker-consumes-high-cpu-for-external-hard-drive)

[image]

The solution from top-voted answer was this command:

```
echo "disable" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe6F
```

In the link `grep` was used to discover the interrupt causing grief:

```
grep . -r /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/
```

---

### Load Average

If you look at your system load average for 1-5-15 minutes like this:

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.50 0.76 0.91 2/1037 14366
```

It's reporting .5, .76 and .91. From [Understanding Linux CPU Load - when should you be worried?](https://scoutapm.com/blog/understanding-load-averages) it says:

> - The **"Need to Look into it"** Rule of Thumb: 0.70 If your load average is staying above > 0.70, it's time to investigate before
>     things get worse.

Further in the article it will mention something like the load average for all your CPUs are added together but not divided by the number of CPUs to get an average of all CPUs. You have to do this manually so the true values are:

.063 - .095 - .113

because I have 8 CPUs.

I prefer to use Conky to display this in real-time though:

[image: conky nvidia.png]

Notice the 4th line from the bottom display 1-5-15 minute load averages as:

```
.150 .177 .143
```

The 1 minute load average of .15 equates to 15% which matches the **All CPU** percentage value two lines above the **Load Average**.

Without diving by 8 I'd have a heart attack because I would be seeing:

```
1.200 1.416 1.144
```

Conky automatically divides for me with the Conky code:

```
${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $2}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4} ${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $3}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
```

Of course not everyone uses conky probably only 1% of Linux users but for those out there that love Conky like me, you might find this code helpful.

Comment: of course load averages can be higher than 1.0 - why do you think otherwise ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl https://superuser.com/questions/1402079/linux-understanding-load-average-and-cpu Did you down vote me just over load average comment?

Comment: So.. nowhere does it state that you can't have a higher load average than 1.0. In fact this -  `A value greater than 1.0 means it's getting more than it can handle` - would directly contradict it ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl You need to divide by 8 is what it confirms... I did rephrase answer to put in "generally" though :)

Comment: okay, still I don't get what you are trying to say. The number 8 comes from 4 cores with HT. OP is experiencing a load increase of a high factor (x5 to x12,5) ... it doesn't matter if he has 2 cores or 128, one socket or 12. The load increase is the issue. Also OP never states how many cores his notebook has or if he has HT... for all we know it could be a dualcore AMD cpu.

Comment: Just remove the part about the load.. it's not correct and it doesn't help OP - while the answer you found might certainly help. Maybe he needs to flip a switch on his HDD caddy.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Thank you. I couldn't find `gpe6F` and there was no entry with trigger counts more than of `3300` in my system. However your link and `@RobertRiedl` comment helped me to fix the issue. It was all about the switch.

Comment: @Ravexina I've marveled at the many times you've helped other users and I'm glad you got helped this time.